# C++ using cout to print cin>> entries problem

Tags: c++, function, printing, cin, cout

I want here to print the result, sname; password; etc, but the program crashes.

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string enter1;
string s;
string sname;
string email;
string password;

string ma()
{
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            cout << "Welcome to our software :D " << endl;
            cout << "Menu :                            " << endl;
            cout << "Enter Your Name :                 " << endl;
            cout << "Enter Your Email:                 " << endl;
            cout << "Enter Your password :             " << endl;
            cout <<"Enter n if you want to print all those results"<<endl;
            cout << "which number ! :";
            cin >> s;
        }
    }

    if (s == "1")
    {
        cout << "Enter Your Name Mate : ";
        cin >> sname;
        ma();
    }
    if (s == "2")
    {
        cout << "Enter Your Email:                 ";
        cin >> email;
        ma();

    }
    if (s == "3")
    {
        cout << "Enter Your Password:                 ";
        cin >> password;
        ma();
        if (s == "n")
        {
            cout << sname;
            cout << email;
            cout << password;
        }

    }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    cout << "Write [e] if you want to open the program :";
    cin >> enter1;
    if (enter1 == "f")
    {
        ma();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You Choose to close the program ......";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the result is like this:

```
Write [e] if you want to open the program :f
Welcome to our software :D 
Menu :                            
Enter Your Name :                 
Enter Your Email:                 
Enter Your password :             
which number ! :1
Enter Your Name Mate : adem  
Welcome to our software :D 
Menu :                            
Enter Your Name :                 
Enter Your Email:                 
Enter Your password :             
which number! :2
Enter Your Email:  adem07@gmail.com
Welcome to our software :D 
Menu :                            
Enter Your Name :                 
Enter Your Email:                 
Enter Your password :             
which number! :3
Enter Your Password:                 dsaddsa
Welcome to our software :D 
Menu :                            
Enter Your Name :                 
Enter Your Email:                 
Enter Your password :             
which number ! :n

RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault; real time: 24s; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Comment: Please fix that formatting/indentation. Why why why would you arrange your code like that, particularly when asking other people to help you fix it for free? Make it neat and easy to read.

Comment: i am sorry bro i agree with you i didn't organize my code and even i forget to change the prhrase of checking if ..... it was wrong phrase

Comment: `ma` promises to return a `string`. It doesn't. That makes the program unstable. You probably want to return `void`

Comment: Recursion is a bad idea for a menu. Every time `ma` calls itself it uses up more memory and will run out. The longer the user runs the program they closer they get to it becoming unstable.

Comment: thank you guys i am just new programmer just trying new things to understand Thank you so much

Comment: Spend some time getting to know the debugger. A debugger allows you to run your program at your speed, not the computer's, and watch what the program really does. It is extremely enlightening and will help you find and resolve bugs much faster. Debuggers are an essential productivity tool for the working programmer.

Comment: Yes i tried to learn programming many years ago but i didn't continue due to many reasons ... but now i have a dream .. i want to learn something every day may be someday i will reach the point where i want to go ^^ thank you all for everything

Comment: I'm sure you'll get there.

Comment: thahk you, same for all of you someday ^^